# What is a good SMTP server for retrieving attachments?

Tags: smtp

I was wondering what a good SMTP server was for retrieving attachments, that allows you to easily set rules to direct and download email content based on stuff like sender, subject line, and easily set rules for what to do after files get to the SMTP site. Also, I want to be able to get attachments to a SMTP folder in a format that isn't encrypted. I was looking into hmail server, but are there any better options?

Answer (score 0):

SMTP servers only allow *sending* messages, not retrieving them or their attachments.

You perhaps want to look into IMAP servers, but *all* IMAP servers allow you to download individual attachments and messages based on Sender, Subject, etc (if you do a search query first), so this question really doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

If I was to choose an IMAP server, I'd probably choose [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/), but that's just me.